# How to solve ''address.setMessage is not a function''?

Tags: web3js, dapps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Deploy a Remix Contract</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Ethereum Secret Messenger</h1>
        <hr>

        <label for="message">This site writes a secret message to the Ethereum
            blockchain!</label>
        <input id="userInput" type="text">

        <button id="setMessageButton">Set secret message</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        // Connect a the web3 provider
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
        }

        // Set a default account
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

        // Get the contract address

        var address = '0xB2E5a4280C67B6Ef89910cb9c99efDc49f3a3FD2'
        var RemixContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_x",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setMessage",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getMessage",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
], address);

        // Get the contract abi


        console.log(RemixContract);

        $("#setMessageButton").click(function () {
            address.setMessage($("#userInput").val());
            console.log($("#userInput").val())
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `address` is defined as a string, so it is not possible to use it to call a contract method.

It is likely the intention was to use `RemixContract`

```
RemixContract.methods.setMessage($("#userInput").val()).send();
```

Read the web3.js documentation for calling smart contracts [`methods.myMethod.send`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).